# Haskell multifilter

Tags: haskell

I want to filter a list by predicates curried from another list.
For instance:

```
multifilter :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
multifilter _ _ [] = []
multifilter _ [] _ = []
multifilter f (x:xs) ys = (filter (f x) ys) ++ (multifilter f xs ys)
```

With usage such as:

```
prelude> multifilter (==) [1,2,3] [5,3,2]
[2,3]
```

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: btw in the appliced case you could also use `filter (\x -> elem x [1,2,3]) [5,3,2]`

Comment: ``ff p xs ys = foldr ((++).(`filter`ys).p) [] xs``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: This answer implements the specification expressed by the words and example in the question, rather than the different one given by the implementation of `multifilter` there. For the latter possibility, see [gallais' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441089/2751851).*

[Sibi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32431764/2751851) shows how you should actually do it. In any case, it is instructive to consider how you might write your function using `filter`. To begin with, we can establish two facts about it:

- `multifilter` can be expressed directly as `filter pred` for some appropriate choice of `pred`. Given a fixed "predicate list", whether an element of the list you are multifiltering will be in the result only depends on the value of that element.
- In `multifilter f xs ys`, the list you are filtering is `xs`, and the "predicate list" is `ys`. Were it not so, you would get `[3,2]` rather than `[2,3]` in your (quite well-chosen) example.

So we have:

```
multifilter :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
multifilter f xs ys = filter pred xs
    where
    pred = undefined -- TODO
```

All we need to do is implementing `pred`. Given an element `x`, `pred` should produce `True` if, for some element `y` of `ys`, `f x y` is true. We can conveniently express that using `any`:

```
pred x = any (\y -> f x y) ys

-- Or, with less line noise:
pred x = any (f x) ys
```

Therefore, `multifilter` becomes...

```
multifilter :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
multifilter f xs ys = filter pred xs
    where
    pred x = any (f x) ys

-- Or, more compactly:
multifilter :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
multifilter f xs ys = filter (\x -> any (f x) ys) xs
```

... which is essentially equivalent to `intersectBy`, as you can see by looking at `intersectBy`'s implementation.

Comment: @dos The ultimate choice is yours, of course, but I feel Sibi's answer is more worthy of the accept. An easily available function from the libraries that does exactly what you want is overall a better solution than a hand-rolled one (even if writing your own can be useful for learning). Besides that, `intersectBy` didn't cross my mind before seeing his answer.

Comment: `multifilter f xs ys = filter (\x -> any (f x) ys) xs` retains values from `xs` when the original question retained values from `ys`. Solving the more general `multifilter :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]` would help detect this mistake.

Comment: @gallais I followed the words and example in the question rather than the implementation there. The inconsistency (that admittedly neither myself nor the other answerers using `intersectBy` had spotted) already lies in the question. That being so, I will not change this answer, but link to yours instead, as it makes a relevant point. See also my comments to your answer.

Comment: @dos By the way, one simple test that illustrates the issue gallais and I are discussing is `multifilter ((==).(2*)) [2,3,12,1] [5,3,2,6]`. Between the four implementations in your question and our two answers there are three different results.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `intersectBy`:

```
λ> :t intersectBy
intersectBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
λ> intersectBy (==) [1,2,3] [5,3,2]
[2,3]
```

You can use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%28a%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20Bool%29%20-%3E%20[a]%20-%3E%20[a]%20-%3E%20[a]) to search functions using type signature and finding them.

Comment: no, `intersectBy` keeps the elements from the first list, not the second.

Comment: @WillNess Does that matter in `==` case ? I think I'm misunderstanding something here. And if we really want to keep elements from the second list, we can just flip the parameter ?

Comment: this should work with `(<)` too (or `((==).(2*))`). simple flipping didn't work for me with both.

Answer (score 4):

A third option is to use a list comprehension:

```
multifilter rel xs ys = [ x | x <- xs, y <- ys, x `rel` y ]
```

or, if you want partial application:

```
multifilter p xs ys = [ x | x <- xs, let f = p x, y <- ys, f y ]
```

If you want to use filter,

```
relate rel xs ys = filter (uncurry rel) $ liftM2 (,) xs ys
```

(and throw in `map fst`)

Comment: nice catch about liftM2! so IOW, ``relate p = (join .) . liftM2 (\x y-> [y|p x y])``. and shouldn't we be keeping `snd`, not `fst` (`y`s, not `x`s)?

Answer (score 2):

The answer you have accepted provides a function distinct from the one defined in your post: it retains elements from `xs` when yours retains elements from `ys`. You can spot this mistake by using a more general type for `multifilter`:

```
multifilter :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]
```

Now, this can be implemented following the specification described in your post like so:

```
multifilter p xs ys = fmap snd
                    $ filter (uncurry p)
                    $ concatMap (\ x -> fmap (x,) ys) xs
```

If you don't mind retaining the values in the order they are in in `ys` then you can have an even simpler definition:

```
multifilter' :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]
multifilter' p xs = filter (flip any xs . flip p)
```

Comment: The root of the difference between our answers is that the question itself is inconsistent. Your first implementation doesn't preserve the order of the list being filtered, `ys`, which would be very surprising behaviour for a filtering function (that is a relevant issue, as the OP says "I want to filter a list"). As for your second implementation, it doesn't match the usage example in the question, as you have pointed out. P.S.: I suggest mentioning that the `(x,)` syntax in the first implementation requires the TupleSections extension.

Comment: @duplode I think the order *is* preserved by the 1st impl-n; 2nd does something completely different, it includes each `y` of `ys` *at most once* in the result (the wording of the question indeed may be interpreted that way).

Comment: @WillNess With the first implementation, `multifilter ((==).(2*)) [9,3,14,1] [5,3,2,6]` results in `[6,2]` -- the elements come from `ys` but are in the order of the matches in `xs`.

Comment: @duplode that *is* what the OP code does too. if we go with the *wording*, then it implies an additional `or`, which the 2nd impl-n captures.

Comment: @WillNess Exactly. That explains how I got from the wording of the question to an implementation equivalent to `intersectBy`.

Comment: @duplode but `intersectBy` keeps the elements of the first list, not the second, and the OP wants to filter the *second* list, i.e. to keep (or not) *its* elements.

Comment: @WillNess But `intersectBy (==) [1,2,3] [5,3,2]` is `[2,3]`, matching the usage example given by the OP. The ambiguity lies in the question itself.

Comment: @duplode  try (<) to see the difference. so the OP chose (==) not wisely. it happens. :)

Comment: @WillNess Yup, the choice of operator is also part of the problem.

Comment: @duplode I have to disagree, it being a parameter to a function, the solution must accomodate *any* operator.

Comment: @WillNess Certainly; I meant part of the problem of how the question is formulated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Hoogle to find it out via the signature `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D

yields `intersectBy`:

```
intersectBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: no, `intersectBy` keeps the elements from the first list, not the second.